# Android layout file doesn't allow charactors such as &, <, >

Tags: java, android, xml

When I tried to use &, <, > as text view text both in main.xml and strings.xml it returns an error. I wanna show "&", "<" sign anyway in my app in the text view. How to do it??

Please advice me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated by @Welbog, there are 5 XML escape sequences you need:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

Source: 
[XML Document Escape Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters)

Answer (score 3):

It's XML. You have to escape them. Maybe you should learn XML before using an XML-based layout language?

```
< &lt;
> &gt;
& &amp;
" &quot; (in attributes)
' &apos; (in attributes)
```

Comment: You've left out &apos; - there are only 5 total.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Android, but in XML use

```
<   =   &lt;
>   =   &gt;
&   =   &amp;
"   =   &quot;
'   =   &apos;
```

Or use [`CDATA`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect) like

```
<![CDATA[
    my String with 
    special chars like
    >, < and &
    normally not allowed in XML!
]]>
```

*Edit 1* Two remaining escape chars for XML is added. Thanks to @[mikaveli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575766/mikaveli)